# Rhino Parse Error (missing ] after element list

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I have a problem executing the build command from my extjs application. See below for the error return:

```
stroy) -- D:\TFS\BS\dev\Litus2ViaBoleto\Litus\Litus\ext\src\ux\TabCloseMenu.js:84
[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (missing ] after element list =>             Litus.store.2viaBoleto,) -- unknown-uri:19:26
[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (syntax error =>         ],) -- unknown-uri:21:9
[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (syntax error =>     )) -- unknown-uri:24:5
[ERR] C2000: Rhino Parse Error (Compilation produced 3 syntax errors. => null) -- unknown-uri:1
[ERR]
[ERR] BUILD FAILED
[ERR] com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: failed optimizing D:\TFS\BS\dev\Litus2ViaBoleto\Litus\Litus\app\store\2viaBoleto\Store.js
[ERR]   at com.sencha.tools.compiler.ast.AstUtil.parse(AstUtil.
[ERR] java:102)
[ERR]
[ERR] Total time: 51 seconds
[ERR] The following error occurred while executing this line:
D:\TFS\BS\dev\Litus2ViaBoleto\Litus\Litus\.sencha\app\build-impl.xml:267: The following
error occurred while executing this line:
D:\TFS\BS\dev\Litus2ViaBoleto\Litus\Litus\.sencha\app\js-impl.xml:83: com.sencha.exceptions.ExBuild: failed optimizing D:\TFS\BS\dev\Litus2ViaBoleto\Litus\Litus\app\store\2viaBoleto\Store.js
```

**Complementary data from my development environment**

ExtJS version: **4.2.2**

Senhca CMD Version: **v6.2.2.35**

Command to build application:

```
sencha app build --clean
```

Thats a store code:

```
/**
 * @class Litus.store.2viaBoleto.Store
 * Store de procura de 2º de Boleto.
 */
Ext.define('Litus.store.2viaBoleto.Store', {
    extend: 'Data.SQLStore',
    database: window.BSConfig.databaseLitus,
    autoLoad: false,
    procedures: {
        select: 'S_2ViaBoleto_L'
    },
    model: 'Litus.model.2viaBoleto.Model'
});
```

Has anyone seen this problem? You can help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by removing the number in the package name of the class. After renaming all occurrences of names starting with number, the problem has been resolved.

I do not remember in ExtJS not to be allowed to use numbers for package naming.

The change was this:

```
store.2viaBoleto.Store
```

To

```
store.SegundaviaBoleto.Store
```